# Add multiple images with cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

First, I have to say that I'm new to rails so sorry for the newbie question.
I have a "Post" model that has many "Pictures"

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['pictures'].nil? }


  belongs_to :user 

  monetize :price

  validates :title, :brand, :model, :price, :year, presence: true

end
```

and my Picture Model :

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  has_attached_file :image,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename",
    styles: { medium: "600x600>"}


  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :image, presence: true

end
```

My create is :

```
def create
  @post = current_user.post.build(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      if params[:images]

        params[:images].each { |image|
        @post.pictures.create(image: image)
        }
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
   else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My strong parameters are :

```
  def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :decription, :brand, :model, :price,  pictures_attributes: [ :image, :_destroy])
end
```

My form :

```
 = simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f|


.form-group
  = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control'}

.form-group
  = f.input :brand, input_html: { class: 'form-control'}

.form-group
  = f.input :model, input_html: { class: 'form-control'}

.form-group
  = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control'}

.form-group
  = f.input :year,  input_html: { class: 'form-control'} 

.form-group
  = f.input :price,  input_html: { class: 'form-control'}



.form-group
  = f.simple_fields_for :pictures do |pic|
    = render 'picture_fields', f: pic

.links
  = link_to_add_association 'add pictures', f, :pictures, class: "btn btn-default"



= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

and

```
.form-inline.clearfix
.nested-fields
    = f.file_field :picture
    = link_to_remove_association "delete", f
```

When i heat the submit button, the post is saved but not able to iterate throw the post pictures in the show.
Is there an error in my code ? Is there a solution to know if the pictures are saved ? When i use the ruby console @post = Post.last and @post.pictures that give me this :

Picture Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE     "pictures"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 34]]
=> #

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) three things wrong here:

Firstly, you shouldn't need to do this (unless naturally there are other ways you use the same controller). `params[:images]` is always nil:

```
if params[:images]
  params[:images].each { |image|
    @post.pictures.create(image: image)
  }
end
```

Second thing, it seems your model has an attribute `image` however in your form you have:

```
= f.file_field :picture
```

Honestly, I would expect this to raise an exception and this is likely the cause of your problem. (If that's the case - you should always post any exception you got together with your question).

And the third thing: it is definitively not the problem you are trying to fix, but most likely your next question you would post after this one has been resolved: you are missing `id` in `pictures_attributes` in your strong params - that would lead you to duplicating all existing images on every form submission + would make it impossible to delete the picture.

EDIT:

Couple of other potential issues. You should always wrap cocoon associations within some wrapper - javascript behind `button_to_add_association` is expecting certain DOM structure, which might be overriden, but it is just easier to just go with a default.

```
 #pictures
  .form-group
    = f.simple_fields_for :pictures do |pic|
      = render 'picture_fields', f: pic

  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'add pictures', f, :pictures, class: "btn btn-default"
```

Another potential problem is your partial. `link_to_remove_association` looks for closest parent with a class `nested-fields` and removes it (unless it is existing record in which case it adds some extra stuff and hides it, not relevant). The problem is that if you add 5 pictures and then removes all of them - you are left with 5 `.form-inline.clearfix` thingies. I don't see your css but that might get your view inconsistent/broken.